# How do I scroll my divs left each time a link is clicked?

Tags: jquery, css

I have taken this code from somewhere and adapted it. I have managed to scroll 400px to the left. But I would like it to scroll left every time I click on the link. The script I am using is:

```
$('.masternav a').bind('click',function(event){
  var $anchor = $(this);
  $('html, body ').stop().animate({
  scrollLeft: (400)}, 1000);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this :

```
$('.masternav a').bind('click',function(event){
            var $anchor = $(this);
            $('html, body ').stop().animate({
                scrollLeft: '+=40'}, 1000);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

This will scroll 40 px each time you click.

Answer (score 0):

If a value is supplied with a leading += or -= sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property. So try this instead :

```
$('.masternav a').bind('click',function(event){
   var $anchor = $(this);
   $('html, body ').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: "+=400")}, 1000);
            event.preventDefault();
});
```

Good Luck !!